# How to generate conditionals programmatically?

Tags: conditional

I need to generate conditionals (||, &&, etc) from a list `conditionList` that I don't know beforehand how many/which elements will it contain.

For simplicity, let's consider integers:

```
conditionList = {3,5};
```

So, taking this list, I'd like to generate the conditionals to filter some other list. For instance:

```
listToBeFiltered={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

Select[listToBeFiltered, (# == 3 || # == 5) &]
```

Here I manually made the argument `(# == 3 || # == 5)` for `Select`. How could I have generated it from `conditionList` directly?

My first guess was to generate the conditions as strings, and then use `ToExpression` to apply it to `Select`, but this does not work:

```
myConditions = 
 StringDrop[
  StringJoin[
   Table[StringJoin["#==", IntegerString[conditionList[[a]]], 
     "||"], {a, 1, Length[conditionList]}]], -2]
```

Gives:

```
#==3||#==5
```

Which when applied gives an empty list:

```
Select[listToBeFiltered, (ToExpression@myConditions) &]

{}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `Select[listToBeFiltered, MemberQ[conditionList, #] &]`

Comment: `Cases[ listToBeFiletered, Alternatives@@conditionList ]`